# Как написать ассемблерную вставку на С++ для НОК четырех натуральных чисел?

Tags: c++, c, ассемблер, visual-studio-2017

День добрый! Вот моя задача:

**Задано четыре натуральных числа. Реализуйте подпрограмму нахождения их наименьшего общего кратного. (реализовать как ассемблерную вставку С++)**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int nod(int a, int b) {
    int rez;
    a = a > 0 ? a : -a;
    b = b > 0 ? b : -b;
    if (a == 0)
        rez = b;
    else if (b == 0)
        rez = a;
    else if (a == b)
        rez = a;
    else if (a == 1 || b == 1)
        rez = 1;
    else {
        int ra = a % 2, rb = b % 2;
        if (!(ra || rb))
           rez = 2 * nod(a / 2, b / 2);
        else if (!ra)
           rez = nod(a / 2, b);
        else if (!rb)
           rez = nod(b / 2, a);
        else if (a > b)
           rez = nod(a - b, b);
        else
           rez = nod(b - a, a);
    }
    return rez;
}

int nok(int a, int b) {
    return a * b / nod(a, b);
}

int main() {
    int a, b, c, d;
    cout << "A, B, C, D\n";
    cin >> a >> b >> c >> d;
    cout << "NOK(A, B, C, D) = " << nok(nok(nok(a, b), c), d) << endl;
    _asm {
    .model small //tasm часть
    .data
    a dw 8
    b dw 12
    .code
    start :
    mov ax, @data
        mov ds, ax

        push a
        push b
        call lcm; //результат в ax

    xor ax, ax
        int 16h
        .exit

        x equ word ptr[bp + 6]
        y equ word ptr[bp + 4]

        gcd:
    push bp
        mov bp, sp
        sub sp, 12
        mov ax, x
        cmp ax, y
        jge @1
        mov ax, x
        mov bx, y
        mov x, bx
        mov y, ax
        @1:
        mov ax, x
        cwd
        mov bx, y
        idiv bx
        test dx, dx
        jne @2
        mov ax, y
        jmp @exit_gcd
        @2:
        push dx
        mov ax, y
        push ax
        call gcd
        @exit_gcd:
        mov sp, bp
        pop bp
        ret

        lcm :
    push bp
        mov bp, sp
        push x
        push y
        call gcd
        mov bx, ax
        mov ax, x
        imul y
        cwd
        idiv bx
        mov sp, bp
        pop bp
        ret

        end start
    }
}
```

Как переделать данную tasm-вставку под вставку ассемблера на C++ без .data и .model small? Проискал просторы Интернета - ничего по этому поводу не нашел.

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, тут 16 битный ассемблер для MS-DOS, который надо переделать в 32 битный. Для этого перед именами всех регистров нужно добавить E (push bp -> push ebp). 
Во-вторых, там в коде 2 функции для НОК и НОД, я решил ctrl+c, ctrl+v их в отдельные naked функции, в которые компилятор не добаляет никакой отсебятины. 
В gcd зачем-то резервируются 12 байт для локальных переменных, которых нет, я просто убрал эту строку. x equ word ptr[bp + 6] y equ word ptr[bp + 4] нужно тоже убрать.
Еще пришлось переименовать некоторые метки, чтобы компиляотр не ругался. 
Получилось так:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


int __declspec(naked) gcd(int x, int y)
{
    __asm {
        push ebp
        mov ebp, esp
        mov eax, x
        cmp eax, y
        jge l1
        mov eax, x
        mov ebx, y
        mov x, ebx
        mov y, eax
        l1 :
        mov eax, x
        cwd
        mov ebx, y
        idiv ebx
        test edx, edx
        jne l2
        mov eax, y
        jmp exit_gcd
        l2 :
        push edx
        mov eax, y
        push eax
        call gcd
        exit_gcd :
        mov esp, ebp
        pop ebp
        ret
    }
}

int __declspec(naked) lcm(int x, int y)
{
    __asm {
        push ebp
        mov ebp, esp
        push x
        push y
        call gcd
        mov ebx, eax
        mov eax, x
        imul y
        cwd
        idiv ebx
        mov esp, ebp
        pop ebp
        ret
    }
}
int main() {
    int a, b, c, d;
    cout << "A, B, C, D\n";
    cin >> a >> b >> c >> d;
    cout << "NOK(A, B, C, D) = " << lcm(lcm(lcm(a, b), c), d) << endl;
}
```